# How can I create an extra journal entry after a document is released?

Tags: acumatica

I want to create a second journal entry after a document, let's say Cash Sale, is released successfully. I've tried to approach this multiple ways, but keep running into different issues.

Where would I have to place the code to create this journal entry after the original journal entry created upon release is made? Some requirements I will need in my code are the screen the original Batch was made from as well as the original document's reference number. If I'm able to get a hold of the first Batch and its GLTran records, that would be well enough for me to make the new record.

Please note that Cash Sale isn't the only document that this will be used for, so if there is a way to centralize this execution, it's a plus, but not required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've crafted this example for CashSale. I believe it's generic enough that you can apply it to your other scenarios too.

Create a graph extension on ARCashSaleEntry and override the Release action:
[image]

Here's the code for the graph extension, explanations are in the code comments:

```
using PX.Data;
using PX.Objects.GL;
using System.Collections;
using ARCashSale = PX.Objects.AR.Standalone.ARCashSale;

namespace PX.Objects.AR
{
    public class ARCashSaleEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<ARCashSaleEntry>
    {
        #region Event Handlers

        public delegate IEnumerable ReleaseDelegate(PXAdapter adapter);

        [PXOverride]
        public IEnumerable Release(PXAdapter adapter, ReleaseDelegate baseMethod)
        {
            // Get reference to current cash sale if required
            ARCashSale cashSale = Base.Document.Current;

            // Declare event handler so we can remove the named delegate
            PXGraph.InstanceCreatedDelegate<JournalEntry> instanceCreatedHandler = null;

            // Handler definition used to intercept Journal Entry Graph
            instanceCreatedHandler = delegate (JournalEntry oldJournalEntry)
            {
                // Remove event handler
                PXGraph.InstanceCreated.RemoveHandler<JournalEntry>(instanceCreatedHandler);

                // Add hook to intercept Batch persisted event
                oldJournalEntry.RowPersisted.AddHandler<Batch>(delegate (PXCache sender, PXRowPersistedEventArgs e)
                {
                    // Get reference to old batch 
                    Batch oldBatch = oldJournalEntry.BatchModule.Current;

                    // After oldBatch is inserted
                    if (oldBatch != null && e.Operation == PXDBOperation.Insert && e.TranStatus == PXTranStatus.Completed)
                    {
                        // Create new Journal Entry Graph
                        JournalEntry newJournalEntry = PXGraph.CreateInstance<JournalEntry>();

                        // Create new batch
                        Batch newBatch = new Batch();

                        // Set new batch properties here and insert it
                        newJournalEntry.BatchModule.Insert(newBatch);

                        // Iterate on old tran from old batch
                        foreach (GLTran oldTran in oldJournalEntry.GLTranModuleBatNbr.Select())
                        {
                            // Create new tran
                            GLTran newTran = new GLTran();

                            // Set new tran properties here and insert it
                            newJournalEntry.GLTranModuleBatNbr.Insert(newTran);
                        }

                        // Save new journal
                        newJournalEntry.Save.Press();
                    }
                });
            };

            // Add hook to intercept Journal Entry Graph
            PXGraph.InstanceCreated.AddHandler<JournalEntry>(instanceCreatedHandler);

            // Call base method to release document
            // Your hook will be called after this action in the context of a PXLongOperation
            return baseMethod(adapter);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: HB, I'm testing and adjusting the code you provided, and I'd have to say you know your stuff! I didn't realize I could add a hook like this. It looks like it is working, but I am running into a small issue I'm working on right now. Since you are hooking into the Persist() method, when you use newJournalEntry.Save.Press(), it calls the function once again! This is leading to an infinite loop. I tried a few things to prevent the infinite loop, but got no where. Any suggestions? Thanks HB!

Comment: I fixed it, but not without going down multiple different routes first. I tried to add a non-persisting, and then db persisting, flag to the Batch DB and set it, but it didn't update properly. I ended up having to add a global flag which I reset after the process was done to prevent the infinite loop. If you have any other suggestions, they are welcome, otherwise thanks for your help, again!

Comment: Removing the event handler should prevent recursion. I updated my answer with that. Also, if you happen to get an exception because two thread touched the same object (another process has...) you can wrap all the code in a PXLongOperation.StartOperation. There can be only one long operation in a call stack so the next call to StartOperation will be ignored and shoehorned in the current long operation.

Comment: Ahh, OK, I see. It looks like you added another handler. I did try to remove the handler, but it wasn't doing it successfully. I'll try your solution above and let you know the results.

Comment: It's the same handler, I just changed it from an anonymous delegate 'AddHandler<JournalEntry>(delegate (...));' to a named delegate so I have a reference to remove it 'AddHandler<JournalEntry>(instanceCreatedHandler)'

Comment: HB, Thank you again for your help above. I have another question related to your answer. Is there any way I can update the ARCashSales Cache? I'm trying to update an extended field on the Document (ARCashSale) view, but when I execute a PressSave(), it errors out saying "Error: Another process has updated the 'CATran' record. Your changes will be lost." I realize that the CATran cache must be getting changed in the release process. Is there any way I can save just the ARCashSale view changes or ignore the CATran when saving?

Comment: I think you can but it has to be updated by the same thread. This isn't really related to my answer, these runtime checks are performed everywhere in the product when you save a record. You can't have 2 different threads/graphs work on the same object without causing save conflict. The fix is usually very specific to the actual code that provoke the conflict so it would be hard to suggest a modification without a full complete exemple.

Comment: Got ya, ok thanks HB! I'm going to try a few more ideas and then if I'm still stuck, I'll post a question.